# Overriding the Object class' equal method

Tags: java, object, overriding, equals

OK so so let's say you have two classes: `ClassA` and `ClassB`

- `ClassA` extends `Object` and `ClassB` extends `ClassA`
- `ClassA` has no argument constructor
- `ClassB` has an integer variable  x and a constructor with an integer argument that initializes x
- `ClassA` doesn't override `equals` that it's inhering from `Object`
- `ClassB` overrides `equals` so that two objects of `ClassB` are considered equal if the integer x has the same value in both objects.

  ```
    //In Class B you have this method:
    public boolean equals (Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!super.equals(obj)) {
            return false;
        }

        B b = (B) obj;

        return this.x == b.x;
    }
  ```

In the main if you were to run this code

```
    B b1 = new B(1);
    B b2 = new B(1);
    System.out.println(b1.equals(b2));
```

I believe "false" would be printed but I'm trying to understand why. Maybe I'm not fully understanding the concept of overriding but I just figured since `B` should be overriding  the `Object.equals` method so it can make sure the x fields are the same.

What appears to be "wrong" that I'm missing?

Comment: What's the point of overriding `equals`, if you are returning the value returned by `super.equals()`?

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 6):

You should omit the

```
if (!super.equals(obj))
{
return false;
 }
```

because that will use the default equals() method (which checks for object identity)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is never going to get past the super.equals check,  because (since `Object.equals` is comparing object references) any two different objects are always going to test false for equality. `Object.equals` is comparing references, the only time it returns true is if it is comparing a reference to itself.

Typically if you override equals it is because you want to compare the objects by value (like String or BigInteger), so there is no reason for referencing the super class's equals method (which compares by reference) in that case.